# grouped summary of a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I've problems to make a summary of a php array. I'm not a pro and all other posts doesn' helped me a lot.
I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position_article_nr] => 100110
            [position_qty] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [position_article_nr] => 100341
            [position_qty] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [position_article_nr] => 100341
            [position_qty] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [position_article_nr] => 100367
            [position_qty] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [position_article_nr] => 100367
            [position_qty] => 1
        )

)
```

and my result should be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position_article_nr] => 100110
            [position_qty] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [position_article_nr] => 100341
            [position_qty] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [position_article_nr] => 100367
            [position_qty] => 2
        )
)
```

position_qty is the sum of identical position_article_nr.
any ideas? thanks

Comment: Mess around with a [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and let us know if you need any further help :)

Comment: Or if this is a database result, maybe `sum` and `group by`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$arr` is your array, `$out` is the final data. It is better and easier to deal with the values of `position_article_nr` as keys of the associate array while counting (no need in search of existing records).

```
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $el)
  if (!isset($out[$el['position_article_nr']]))
     $out[$el['position_article_nr']] = $el;
  else
     $out[$el['position_article_nr']]['position_qty'] += $el['position_qty'];

var_dump($out);
```

If you want to remove keys from `$out` just make `$out = array_values($out);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect! I have some trouble to understand it but i will study that and keep going to learn it!

Comment: @Marco ask questions if something is unclear. It uses `100367` and so on as a key of the associative array. This way it is easier to check or to address to the 'stored' previously values.

Comment: i understand the logic about the key and the code: proof of existing array with key `xxxxxx`, when not set set it else add qty to position_qty. but the style of $out[$el['position_article_nr']] = $el is a little bit confusing for me :/ but i will understand it soon hopefully

Comment: @Marco it takes the value of `$el['position_article_nr']` and uses it as a key for elements of array `$out`. If you will look at `var_dump` provided in example, you will understand what I mean.